# MEAN STACK Routing - doing order

Tags: node.js, express, routes, mean-stack

I am a MEAN stack beginner and i cannot find a solution for my routing problem.
I would like to divide all routes from the app.js file, so i create a file which contains all routes of my application.
I get a NOT FOUND issue or an infinite cycle request.

This is what i have in my **app.js**

```
app.use(require('./routes/config'));
```

And here what there is in the **routes/config**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/partials/:name', require('./partials'));
router.get('/api/tickets', require('./api/tickets'));
router.get('/tickets', require('./tickets'));
router.get('/', require('./index'));


module.exports = router;
```

and in one route i have:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Could you please help me and tell me what is wrong and why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you want to achieve with it? you want the filename param to be the value for the name or something else?

Comment: I want to create a single page application, but my routing not work. I updated the question, i would like to render the index page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your config file you need to use the router like this:

```
router.use('/partials/:name', require('./partials'));
```

and for the partials will be a route, in your partials file omit the `next` attribute;

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index');
});
```

Comment: Thank you! it works! Can you tell me why before didn't work?

Comment: you were using the `router.get` function that expect a function for the second parameter. you could put there the `function(req, res) { .. `.